# Display python list as table in html

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-filters

I am struggling to format my list as a table in html (I am using django). Usually, I can easily achieve this by a for loop, like this:

```
<tbody>
    {% for item in lyrics %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{lyrics}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

But this gives me the *whole* list in every table cell.

If I do it like this...

```
  <tr>
      <td>{{lyrics.0}}</td>
      <td>{{lyrics.1}}</td>
    </tr>
```

...it works. But obviously I don't want to write it out for all n items.

I was hoping I can do something like...

```
{% for i in lyrics.i % }
     {{lyrics.i}}
```

But that didn't work either.

The following works in terms of getting the results neatly below each other, but obviously it's not a table:

```
<ol class='lyrics-list'>
          {{ lyrics|unordered_list }}
        </ol>
```

My list comes from my view:

```
lyrics = models.Song.objects.get().lyrics_as_list()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you specify `for item in lyrics`, you want to use `item` as your table cell element, rather than `lyrics`. That is, it seems like you want:

```
{% for item in lyrics %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{item}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Here's why: This `for` loop, creates a `<td>` element for every single element in `lyrics`. When you set the loop up, the identifier you used for each individual element is `item`. For each iteration of this loop, `item` contains a single element of `lyrics`.

Comment: Damn, now I feel silly! Thank you for your clear explanation! :)